# Instalar aplicativo feito no Visual Studio na máquina do cliente

Tags: c#, winforms

Criei meu primeiro aplicativo Windows Forms e irei instalar na máquina do cliente. Como devo proceder? Basta apenas o `.exe` e o banco de dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em geral não.

Primeiro, precisa ter o .NET Framework, na versão que você exigiu na sua aplicação, instalado na máquina. Se não tiver, ele precisa ser enviado junto e instalar antes.

É comum ter outras dependências além do `.exe`. Normalmente outros arquivos são necessários também.

Quando fala o banco de dados está falando do software ou da sua base? Se for o software, sim precisa, a não ser que possa garantir que ele esteja instalado. Se for a base, depende de como vai inserir no sistema.

Mas estamos falando do lado do cliente, certo? O banco de dados não é do lado do servidor? Se for, deveria ser uma instalação separada. Se a aplicação for verdadeiramente cliente-servidor, pode botar o banco de dados pra funcionar junto com o software servidor, se o cliente acessar o banco de dados diretamente então talvez nem seja o caso de ter um instalador. Talvez seja só o caso de uma aplicação normal que carrega os dados no servidor de banco de dados. Conforme for, pode ser até um *script* simples, não precisa ser um executável.

Então é **possível** só copiar os arquivos e tudo funcionar. Isso é chamado de [*XCOPY installing*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302347(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em alguns casos é preciso fazer algumas configurações extras.

Por isso é comum usar um instalador para fazer isso. O Visual Studio provê um simples e que resolve boa parte dos casos. Nas versões mais novas do VS vai querer instalar uma [extensão com projeto de instalação](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Existe uma [quantidade enorme de instaladores mais completos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software), a maioria pagos.

O instalador tem a vantagem que ele pode cuidar de instalar ou atualizar o .NET Framework.

Note que é possível fazer sem um instalador, mas costuma haver algum trabalho manual necessário e copiar tudo corretamente.

Também existe a possibilidade do [Click Once](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/142dbbz4(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é uma tecnologia do .NET onde a pessoa clica no pacote e tudo começa funcionar, sem uma instalação oficial. Não é fácil fazer ele funcionar adequadamente e não costuma ser o que a pessoa deseja. Nem tem documentação atualizada. Há casos pra ele, mas é raro.

Há quem crie seu próprio instalador.

Uma outra coisa que precisa analisar é a atualização. É até mais complicada, e poucos fazem certo.

Note que para o .NET Core ou só .NET começando na versão 5 nada disso é válido, é tudo diferente, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: poxa, é mais complicado que pensei rsrsrs. vou baixar a extensão que você falou e ver se consigo usá-la. Você pode me passar algum link falando sobre como usar a extensão e sobre a atualização?

Comment: Não achei nada útil, como eu nunca a usei, não posso falar muito.

Comment: Tá bom, obrigado mesmo assim ;)

Comment: Segui esse tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU e consegui criar o instalador. Irei agora na casa de um amigo testar se consigo instalar no pc dele